# Excel counting rows that are not empty in Vlookup value

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, countif

I'm trying to count the total number of cells that have values for the row that I'll be looking up using their name. I have a different sheet for looking up the value I tried COUNTA and VLOOKUP. Is there any way to combine these two so I'll end up with the correct result?

Please see screenshot.

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX(,MATCH()):

```
=COUNTA(INDEX('Sheet1'!C:X,MATCH("Jessel Rayes",'Sheet1'!A:A,0),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vba function that looks up the value you define (first input) in a specified range (second input) and then returns the number of empty cells in the same row right from this cell for a specified amount of columns (third input).

```
 Function TLookupT(Value As Variant, arr As Range, column As Long)

  x = 0
  For Each Cell In arr
    If Cell.Value = Value Then
        For i = 1 To column - 1
            If Cell.Offset(0, i) = "" Then
            x = x + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
 Next Cell

 TLookupT = x

 End Function
```